# React Native: Issue with Animated API - Animation Not Triggering on State Change

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently facing an issue with the React Native Animated API. I'm trying to trigger an animation based on a state change, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Animated, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const [animation] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

  const handlePress = () => {
    Animated.timing(animation, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Log to check if state change triggers animation
    console.log('State changed!');
  }, [animation]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.box, { opacity: animation }]}>
        <Text>Animated Box</Text>
      </Animated.View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress}>
        <Text>Trigger Animation</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  box: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
  },
});
```

Despite logging the state change correctly, the animation doesn't seem to be triggered. I've ensured that the useNativeDriver is set to false and tried different approaches, but none have worked.

Can someone please provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue with the Animated API not triggering on a state change? Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger a state change, you need to use second return of useState hook which is a function.

```
const [animation, setAnimation] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
```

when you use setAnimation DOM will notices that state is changed and rerender will be triggered.